# Printing specific path to a node in a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, traversal, preorder

I'm trying to use pre-order traversal to find a node in a binary tree made up of the characters a-z and A-Z, where going left is marked as "0" and going right is marked as "1", so that a correct output would look like "00" for a node that is two branches to the left. The nodes are not sorted.

So far I have this:

```
static String routeNum = "";      

private static String onePath(BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root, String route) {

    BinaryNodeInterface<Character> temp = root;
    if(temp != null){

    if(temp.hasLeftChild()){
      routeNum = onePath(temp.getLeftChild(),route+"0");

      }
      if(temp.hasRightChild()){
       routeNum = onePath(temp.getRightChild(), route+"1");

      }
    }

    System.out.print(route);
    return route;
}
```

The output indicates that I am getting to the right nodes but it doesn't print the path.

Comment: You need to called System.out.println() or there _won't_ be any output.

Comment: `routeNum = route + "0"; onePath(temp.getLeftChild(),route+"0");`                                     
`routeNum = route + "1"; onePath(temp.getRightChild(), route+"1");`. Clean way to do this is to use StringBuffer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code without the static String routeNum = "";

```
private static String onePath(BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root, String route) {

BinaryNodeInterface<Character> temp = root;
if(temp != null){

if(temp.hasLeftChild()){
  route += "0";
  onePath(temp.getLeftChild(),route);

  }
  if(temp.hasRightChild()){
   route += "1";
  onePath(temp.getRightChild(), route);

  }
}

system.out.println(route);
return route;
```

}

Call this function with

```
String path = onePath(root, "");
Print(path);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are never calling a print method.  You can use:

```
System.out.println(route);
```

to print out the route String.

Comment: I tried that but it prints out a path for every node. I have another method that is supposed to do that, which is where I copied this method from.

Comment: do something like String toPrint = onePath(root, ""); and then call System.out.println(toPrint);